# kvm virtual manager connection failed

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, kvm

I installed kvm package in the centos7 i am getting this problem how to solve this.
[image]

full error is here

```
Unable to connect to libvirt.

no connection driver available for qemu:///system

Libvirt URI is: qemu:///system

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 969, in _open_thread
    self._backend.open(self._do_creds_password)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/connection.py", line 157, in open
    open_flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 105, in openAuth
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirtError: no connection driver available for qemu:///system
```

more info

```
[AsNaDa@localhost ~]$ systemctl is-enabled libvirtd.service
enabled
[AsNaDa@localhost ~]$ systemctl is-active libvirtd.service
active

[AsNaDa@localhost ~]$ rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libvirt/connection-driver/libvirt_driver_qemu.so
libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu-1.2.8-16.el7_1.2.x86_64
[AsNaDa@localhost ~]$

Welcome to virsh, the virtualization interactive terminal.

Type:  'help' for help with commands
       'quit' to quit

virsh #
```

Comment: Have you installed package `libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu` ?

Comment: already installed and its a latest version too.

Comment: Please, run `virsh` command locally on a machine and show us your output.

Comment: I just updated the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem in CentOS 7.
In my case upgrading `device-mapper-libs` solved the issue:

```
yum upgrade device-mapper-libs
```

In my case, some hints were given by checking status of `libvirtd`:

```
service libvirtd status
```

There were errors like below, so if you have similar problem, upgrading `device-mapper-libs` should help.

```
Oct 18 17:55:34 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[6130]: failed to load
module /usr/lib64/libvirt/connection-driver/libvirt_driver_storage.so
/usr/lib64/libvirt/connection-driver/libvirt_driver_storage.so: symbol
dm_task_...k time reference

Oct 18 17:55:34 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[6130]: failed to load 
module /usr/lib64/libvirt/connection-driver/libvirt_driver_qemu.so 
/usr/lib64/libvirt/connection-driver/libvirt_driver_qemu.so: undefined
symbol: virStorageFileCreate<br>
```

Answer (score 3):

To have possibility to run `virt-manager` correctly on the same machine as you'd like to control it (locally), you'll need to install the following packages:

`qemu-kvm
qemu-img
virt-manager
libvirt
libvirt-python
python-virtinst
libvirt-client
virt-install 
virt-viewer`

Re-check if they are all correctly installed on your server, or simply run the following statement:

`# yum -y install qemu-kvm qemu-img virt-manager libvirt libvirt-python python-virtinst libvirt-client virt-install virt-viewer`

If some of described packages are not installed on your system, they'll be installed (and packages that are existing will be skipped).

Also, the following systemd services should be enabled and running on the machine:
`libvirtd.service
libvirtd.socket
libvirt-guests.service`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, restarting the libvirtd service fixed it for me:

```
sudo service libvirtd stop
sudo service libvirtd start
```